# How to count the number of participants with multiple observations/rows that have a combination of values in different rows of a column?

Tags: r, filter, group-by, dplyr

I have a dataset were each participant has multiple observations (column name=id). In each observation each participant is given a diagnosis (column name=diagnosis).

I would like to count the number of participants who have a specific combination of diagnoses.

Please find a reproducible example of R code below. I have tried to group the data by id, filter by the combination of two diagnoses, and then count the number of participants, but this returns no data.

Do you see any solutions?

Thank you!

```
library(tidyverse)
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
diagnosis <- c("a101", "b101", "a101",
               "c101", "c101", "c101",
               "b101", "a101", "b101")
data <- data.frame(id, diagnosis, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

n_a101_and_b101 <- data %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 filter((substr(diagnosis,1,4)=="a101") & 
        (substr(diagnosis,1,4)=="b101")) %>%
 tally()

n_a101_and_b101
```

Comment: The `&` needs to be `|`. `(substr(diagnosis, 1,4)=="a101") |        (substr(diagnosis,1,4)=="b101")`. diagnosis can not be `a101` and `b101` at the same time.

Comment: You don't need to use `substr` as you are trying to spot exact matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there is a nicer tidyverse-style pipe answer, but I would do this via set operations:

Get the set of diagnosis_1 and 
get the set of diagnosis_2 and then 
find the intersection, 
i.e. the rows that are present in both sets.

```
a <- filter(data, diagnosis == "a101")
b <- filter(data, diagnosis == "b101")
intersect(a$id, b$id)
[1] 1 3
length(intersect(a$id, b$id))
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(tidyverse)

id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
diagnosis <- c("a101", "b101", "a101",
               "a101", "c101", "c101",
               "b101", "a101", "b101")

data <- data.frame(id, diagnosis, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(sum(diagnosis == "a101") * sum(diagnosis == "b101") > 0) %>%
  distinct(id) %>%
  nrow()

# [1] 2
```

You can also use `filter("a101" %in% diagnosis & "b101" %in% diagnosis)` as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

There might be several ways to achieve this. I just modified your code:

```
ab101 <- data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(yes = (max(diagnosis == "a101") + 
                  max(diagnosis == "b101"))==2) %>% 
  summarise(yes = yes[1])
sum(ab101$yes)
```

[1] 2